# How can I preload a Core Data database as a part of the build process for an iPhone project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

Here's my situation, and it's probably fairly common but I have yet to find a satisfactory way to do it.

I am developing an iPhone application that will have a read-only, pre-loaded Core Data database stored in the app's bundle. I completely understand how to deploy such a thing. That isn't my problem.

My problem is *How do I pre-load the Core Data database as a part of my build process?* I can imagine several ways to do this, but I'm looking for a solution that integrates best with Xcode and has the least amount of hackery.

So far, my #1 choice is to create a project for a command-line tool that shares the Core Data Model with the iPhone project. This tool could then be run as a part of a shell script phase of the iPhone project's build process. What sucks is that, because one is an iPhone project and the other an OS X command-line tool, they cannot share the same project or even be referenced from one to the other. They must be completely separate. :(

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on where you are getting the data from.  Sounds like you are pulling the data from somewhere else automatically.  In that case I would build a command line tool as you have guessed but don't rebuild it.  Just create a command line tool and then execute it in a shell script as part of the build process for the iPhone application.

There should not be any reason to re-build that command line tool unless your model is updated.

Comment: I suspected as much. This is exactly what I intended to do barring any other responses. Unfortunately I suspect my model will change a fair amount during the early stages of development, which could make this a mildly annoying process, but that's the way it goes.

Comment: if your data is changing slightly during development just let automatic migration take care of it as much as possible.  Then when you are nearly done do a new data file.

Answer (score 1):

> because one is an iPhone project and the other an OS X command-line tool, they cannot share the same project or even be referenced from one to the other

That's a limitation in the new Xcode; it used to be perfectly possible to build a command line tool to run tests on OSX (and, in fact, it still works with xcodebuilder, just not in Xcode itself).

**EDIT:** A very terrible hack is to use PyObjC so you can run things in Python, but that's probably not suitable if you need to use compiled things.

A workaround is to do the data conversion on first launch.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using a compiler flag so that it would do the data conversion on first launch, but I think the approach of using a separate app is probably best.